# Set Text to the lowest right edge of a label?

Tags: c#, winforms, label

Easy example, lets say I'm creating a Label like that:

```
Label label = new Label();
label.Text = "Hello" + "20.50";
label.Width = 250;
label.Height = 100;
panel1.Controls.Add(label);
```

How could I say that the "20.50" should appear in the lowest right edge of the label?

For clarity I made a little example in word:

[image]

How could I achieve this? Any help appreciated!

Comment: `label.Text = "Hello" + "20.50"` is the same to `label.Text = "Hello20.50"`. So what is the rule to determine what should be on the top-left corner and what should be on the bottom-right corner?

Comment: there is no such rule.. in my real example I have an object, lets say "House".. House has 2 Properties: "Name" and "Number"... now I would form the text: `label.Text = house.Name + house.Number` and that (house)number always should appear in the bottom-right corner..

Comment: Create a custom usercontrol consisting of two labels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in support for this with a Label control. You'll need to inherit from Label to create a custom control, and then write the painting code yourself.

Of course, you'll also need some way to differentiate between the two strings. The `+` sign, when applied to two strings, is concatenation. The two strings are joined together by the compiler, so all you get is this: `Hello20.50`. You will either need to use two separate properties, each with their own strings, or insert some sort of delimiter in between the two strings that you can use to split them apart later. Since you're already creating a custom control class, I'd go with the separate properties—much cleaner code, and harder to get wrong.

```
public class CornerLabel : Label
{
   public string Text2 { get; set; }

   public CornerLabel()
   {
      // This label doesn't support autosizing because the default autosize logic
      // only knows about the primary caption, not the secondary one.
      // 
      // You will either have to set its size manually, or override the
      // GetPreferredSize function and write your own logic. That would not be
      // hard to do: use TextRenderer.MeasureText to determine the space
      // required for both of your strings.
      this.AutoSize = false;
   }

   protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   {
      // Call the base class to paint the regular caption in the top-left.
      base.OnPaint(e);

      // Paint the secondary caption in the bottom-right.
      TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics,
                            this.Text2,
                            this.Font,
                            this.ClientRectangle,
                            this.ForeColor,
                            TextFormatFlags.Bottom | TextFormatFlags.Right);
   }
}
```

Add this class to a new file, build your project, and then drop this control onto your form. Make sure to set both the `Text` and `Text2` properties, and then resize the control in the designer and watch what happens!

Comment: +1 for using the existing default text drawing, :) I forgot that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you need, a custom label:

```
public class CustomLabel : Label
{
    public CustomLabel()
    {
        TopLeftText = BottomRightText = "";
        AutoSize = false;
    }
    public string TopLeftText {get;set;}        
    public string BottomRightText {get;set;}                
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat() { LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near})
        {
            using(SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor)){
              e.Graphics.DrawString(TopLeftText, Font, brush, ClientRectangle, sf);
              sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;
              sf.Alignment =  StringAlignment.Far;
              e.Graphics.DrawString(BottomRightText, Font, brush, ClientRectangle, sf);
            }
        }
    }
}
//use it:
//first, set its size to what you want.
customLabel1.TopLeftText = house.Name;
customLabel2.BottomRightText = house.Number;
```

Comment: Except don't use `DrawString`. Prefer `TextRenderer.DrawText` to match the way WinForms draws controls.

Comment: Well, `DrawText` uses GDI, which is what Windows uses internally for the UI. `DrawString` is GDI+. There's plenty of information about it online. I've probably posted an answer on it myself. (Also, if you're going to use `TextRenderer.MeasureText`, you have to use the same subsystem to draw the text. The measurements will be slightly different. Use `MeasureString` if you're using `DrawString`.)

Comment: @CodyGray thank you, I wish I could vote up your answer more 1 time. It's much simpler and better than mine. The code I posted here is not complete, it won't work if `Font` is changed at runtime, it doesn't wrap text, ...unless I add more code to handle some more events :)

Comment: Your code is easy enough to fix, though. There's no reason to track the size of both strings in a private variable. You can calculate that dynamically whenever a repaint happens. That gets rid of about half the code right there, including the need to handle events. Then you'd change `DrawString` to `DrawText`, which would not only improve rendering, but also allow you to avoid creating (and in this case leaking) a new brush.

Comment: @CodyGray OK, I may use `DrawText` in other code but not in this answer because it will may look like your answer, I add more `using` and found that the combination of `LineAlignment` and `Alignment` would make the same effect as of `TextFormatFlags`, just edited and it looks OK now except that the default text drawing should be used as in your answer. However it's enough for this question of mine, otherwise it may be some copy of your code.